# Can you stop people from adding you to RCS group chats?

Tags: spam, rich-communication-services

I keep getting added to RCS group chats by Nigerian/Filipino numbers asking for my credit card details, so I would like to know if there's something I can do to stop that.

Can I require my approval before I can be added to groups? Is it possible to disable group chats without disabling RCS entirely?

Comment: RCS replaces the standard SMS/MMS software but otherwise works under the same principles. As such, you can't prevent being sent messages using RCS the sane way you can't prevent being sent any other SMS. That is, unless you proactively block the offending numbers. Any modern Android phone will let you do that.